# Pivot table in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Am new to  MySQL, I want to pivot a table
Table contains two columns only `Name` and `Occupation` Where no `null` values are `inserted`

I want to pivot the occupation column so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor
I tried this query, Where am able to get them to the point where the column is pivoted

```
SELECT ( CASE 
           WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' THEN NAME 
           ELSE NULL 
         END ) AS 'Doctor', 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN occupation = 'Professor' THEN NAME 
           ELSE NULL 
         END ) AS 'Professor', 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN occupation = 'Singer' THEN NAME 
           ELSE NULL 
         END ) AS 'Singer', 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN occupation = 'Actor' THEN NAME 
           ELSE NULL 
         END ) AS 'Actor' 
FROM   occupations 
ORDER  BY NAME;
```

My output as:

```
Aamina NULL NULL NULL
NULL Ashley NULL NULL
NULL Belvet NULL NULL
NULL Britney NULL NULL
NULL NULL Christeen NULL
NULL NULL NULL Eve
NULL NULL Jane NULL
NULL NULL NULL Jennifer
NULL NULL Jenny NULL
Julia NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL Ketty
NULL NULL Kristeen NULL
NULL Maria NULL NULL
NULL Meera NULL NULL
NULL Naomi NULL NULL
Priya NULL NULL NULL
NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL Samantha
```

I can't figure a way out how can I can get output like:

```
Aamina Ashley Christeen Eve
Julia Belvet Jane Jennifer
Priya Britney Jenny Ketty
NULL Maria Kristeen Samantha
NULL Meera NULL NULL
NULL Naomi NULL NULL
NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
```

If someone could explain it to me, It would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. But, for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I have read it now and I'll surely take care of it, Thank you

Comment: I'm not holding my breath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with window functions (available in MySQL 8.0) and aggregation:

```
select 
    max(case when occupation = 'Doctor'    then name end) doctor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) professor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Singer'    then name end) singer,
    max(case when occupation = 'Actor'     then name end) actor
from (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) rn
    from occupations o
) o
group by rn
```

Comment: Thank you, But Can You explain what you did? and why you did?

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya: Sure. The subquery ranks records having the same occupation by ascending name. Then the outer query does the pivoting, and puts each occupation in a different column. You can run the subquery and stare at the results to better understand how this works.

Comment: Thank you have understood what you did and also now I know that I need to improve in subquery and aggregate functions.